# Is there any CDO or NCO function to truncate netCDF values?

Tags: netcdf, truncate, cdo-climate, nco

I am dealing with slight negative values (after de-accumulate a cumulative precipitation array), which I suppose are numerical artifacts due to precision, and I want to truncate all values x<0 and assign them as 0.

Is there any function to truncate values in CDO/NCO? I cannot find them.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to use either expr or aexpr in CDO, which lets you do simple arithmetic to create new variables

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164297/setting-values-below-a-threshold-to-the-threshold-in-a-netcdf-file - please use cdo-climate to tag future "climate data operator" questions - cdo is ambiguous as there are at least 3 "cdo"s out there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A concise way to truncate is with `ncap2`'s clipping operator `>>` documented [here](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html/clp):

```
ncap2 -s 'precip = precip >> 0' in.nc out.nc
```