# How to update portion of the netCDF file?

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

I have netCDF files with 1500 rows and 2000 columns. Few of them contain inconsistencies in data at different locations. I want to update such inconsistencies with NoData values. While researching I found many answers where one would like to update variable values above/below a certain threshold.  For example:

```
#------ Research-----

dset['var'][:][dset['var'][:] < 0] = -1

#-----------------
```

[Python : Replacing Values in netcdf file using netCDF4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865410/python-replacing-values-in-netcdf-file-using-netcdf4)

Since, the values of inconsistencies match with the data values, updating inconsistencies based on below / above a certain threshold value is not possible.

My approach 1:

```
ncfile   =   r'C:\\abcd\\55618_12.nc'
variableName =  'MAX'   

fh = Dataset(ncfile, mode='r+')

for i in range(500,600,1):
    for j in range(200,300,1):
        fh.variables[variableName][i][j] = -99900.0 # NoData value
        #--- or 
        #fh.variables[variableName][i:j] = -99900.0

fh.close()
```

Approach 2:

```
fh = Dataset(ncfile, mode='r')
val = fh.variables[variableName]

for i in range(500,600,1):
    for j in range(200,300,1):
        val[i][j] = -99900.0

fh = Dataset(ncfile, mode='w') #(ncfile, mode='a')(ncfile, mode='r+')
fh.variables[variableName] = val
fh.close()
```

Result:
The scripts completes processing successfully. However do not update the .nc file.

Friends, your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following approach worked for me:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np

ncfile   =   r'C:\\abcd\\55618_12.nc'
variableName =  'MAX'

fh = nc.Dataset(ncfile, mode='r')
val = fh.variables[variableName][:]
fh.close()

print type (val)

for i in range(500,600,1):
    for j in range(200,300,1):
        #print i,j
        val[i][j] = -99900.0
        if val[i][j]> -99900.0:
            print val[i][j]


fh = nc.Dataset(ncfile, mode='r+')
fh.variables[variableName][:]= val
fh.close()
```

Comment: You question is a bit unclear. Do you always want to set the range `i=500:600, j=200:300` to your fill value? In that case, simply use `val[500:600,200:300] = -99900.0` (so without the double loop). And if you directly open the file as `r+`, you don't need to open it twice..

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. The range changes for different files. The provided information is helpful. especially r+ mode information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is the data on a lat/lon grid?  If so it may be easier to do it from the command line using cdo:

```
cdo setclonlatbox,FillValue,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2  infile.nc outfile.nc
```

Where FillValue is your missing value which seems to be -99900.0 in your case.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. Thanks for the cdo information. It is helpful.

Comment: If this solved your problem then you can accept it as an answer by clicking the tick below the arrows.